# Как изменить фон ячейки таблицы в зависимости от условия?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно, чтобы при фразе «Да» ячейка закрашивалась зелёным, а при фразе «Нет» – красным.

Пробовал таким способом, но результат не тот, что нужен. Как правильно сделать?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x = $('td.tb').text();
    if (x = 'Да') $('td.tb').css({color: 'green'});
});
```

Comment: а какой результат и какой нужен?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Например так

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>titile</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    .red {
      background-color: red;
    }
    .green {
      background-color: green;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('td:contains("да")').addClass('red');
      $('td:contains("нет")').addClass('green');
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>да</td>
      <td>нет</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Если в ячейке написать «да нет, не стоит..», применятся оба класса

Comment: @Sergiks полагаю у него таблица single-значений. У него в коде подобная проверка.